# Jest Test how to handle when a mixed answer String and int is expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, jestjs, supertest

I am running a test for an app that generates an ID (random number) for a customer after a creation, since the number is a random how can I make sure that the number created has 10 digits?

Here is the code

```
 describe('POST/accounts/', () => {

  var resquestBody = {"name:" "Paul", "age":23, "profession":"teacher"}
  
  it ('test member creation', async () => {
   const req = await  request
   .post('/accounts')
   .send(requestBody')
   .expect(200)
  expect(req.body).toEqual('')
  })
})
```

the answer that the application gerates is a 10 number length.
something like:

```
     {ID: 2123212321}
```

My doubt is how can a make sure that the number generated has 10 digits and is referent to the ID.

I tried

```
     expect(res.body)toHaveProperty('ID')
```

But with this sintaxe I can only test that it has the ID but not the number itself.

any suggestions?

Comment: You can try like this expect(res.body.id.length).toEqual(10)

Comment: Couldn't you just test that the id is a number between the lowest value for those digits and highest?  Like 4 digit number is a number between 1000 and 9999.  You remove string conversions and simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

`let id = res.body.id + ''; //convert to string if number`
`expect(id.length).toEqual(10); // validate string length`

Or you can also have a REGEX of ID and validate if the format was correct using the `toEqual` method.

Answer (score 0):

With your help I resolved my issue like this:

```
  describe('POST/accounts/', () => {

  var resquestBody = {"name:" "Paul", "age":23, "profession":"teacher"}


 it ('test member creation', async () => {
 const req = await  request
 .post('/accounts')
 .send(requestBody')
 .expect(200)
 expect(req.body).toHaveProperty('ID')
 expect(req.body.id).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1000000000);
 expect(req.body.id).toBeLessThan(9999999999);
})
})
```

Thank you again for your help!